# Differences between various consoles in Python

Tags: web-scraping, anaconda

I am trying to make run a script for webscraping. However, I feel the problem could be that I keep running the written script in the wrong console.

So far I could not really understand the differences between the consoles cmd and Anaconda Prompt. Anaconda Navigator looks rather like an administrative tool, but it seems still to make a difference for my code whether I use a terminal from there or not. Could anyone elaborate on that?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. cmd: command-prompt, that used to run our python script, especially for scripts with .py extension. Besides that, we can used to install python library
2. Anaconda Prompt: almost similar to cmd. But usually we used to open jupyter notebook or other console on Anaconda Navigator.
3. Anaconda Navigator: a GUI desktop application that is included in the Anaconda installation package. Through Anaconda Navigator, programmers can easily run and manage Conda packages, environments and channels without the need to use command prompt commands. Anaconda Navigator can search for packages in the anaconda cloud repository.

So, the difference depends on what we want to do. You can't judge the problem arises because of the wrong console. It depends on the error message that appears.

Suggestion: read the error message, and analyze or find a way to solve the problem

Comment: Much appreciated. arjun